# Spotting the implicit coercion?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Looking at this destructuring assignment ( ES6) :

```
var {a, b} = {a:1, b:2}
console.log(b); //2
```

It is clear that `a` will be `1` and `b` will be `2`.

[Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=var%20%7Ba%2C%20b%7D%20%3D%20%7Ba%3A1%2C%20b%3A2%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(b)%3B%20%2F%2F2) treats it as :

```
"use strict";
var _a$b = { a: 1, b: 2 };
var a = _a$b.a;
var b = _a$b.b;
console.log(b);
```

OK.

But looking at this code :

```
var { x : { y = 10 } } = { x : 15 };
console.log(y); //10
```

As you can [see](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=var%20%7B%20x%20%3A%20%7B%20y%20%3D%2010%20%7D%20%7D%20%3D%20%7B%20x%20%3A%2015%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20console.log(y)%3B%20%2F%2F10) the result is `10`. According to Kyle Simpson , there is an implicit coercion here.

**Question:**

What is the implicit coercion that happens here and why/how does `y` is `10` ?

Comment: This looks like `{ expr; }` is being treated as it's own code block, `y` may not even be `var`d, check if it's going into a scope or the global object

Comment: On Nightly I get `SyntaxError: missing : after property id`.

Comment: Would you mind quoting or linking Kyle Simpson?

Comment: @bergi Yes here it is https://mobile.twitter.com/ydkjs/status/572424505513140224

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is destructuring with a default initialiser. What happens is:

1. The `{x: 15}` object is destructured on the expression `{x: …}`
2. The `x` property is matched
3. The value `15` is destructured on the expression `{y = 10}` (shorthand for `{y: y = 10}`). For this, it is **implicitly coerced** to an object - like `new Number(15)`
4. the `y` property cannot be matched, because Numbers don't have one - so the default value is taken and the initialiser is evaluated (to 10)
5. The value `10` is assigned to the `y` variable.

You can also [try](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=var%20%7B%20x%20%3A%20%7B%20toExponential%20%3D%2010%20%7D%20%7D%20%3D%20%7B%20x%20%3A%2015%20%7D%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(toExponential)%3B%20%2F%2F) changing the `y` to a property that exists on `Number.prototype` for a different result.